# Iexplore ignores folder view settings

Tags: windows-xp, internet-explorer, windows-explorer

when I click on a hyperlink pointing to a folder in Internet Explorer, up comes the folder in windows explorer, but always with Large Icons display mode.

Is there any way I can configure it to show me the folder in details view?

Answer (score 2):

Tutorial (with Vid): http://ask-leo.com/how_do_i_get_windows_explorer_to_display_details_by_default.html

Crux:

1. Change view to "Details"
2. Go to Tools, Folder Options, and click on the View tab.
3. Press the "Apply to All Folders" button.

Enjoy.